# iPad 4 Width/Height confused?

Tags: xcode, ipad, height, width

I've been working on adapting an iPhone app to iPad. Due to a number of assets which have to be scaled and placed differently, there's some work to be done in terms of relocating everything.

One thing I've noticed is that on the iPad mini, if we use this code:

```
CGFloat height = [UIScreen mainScreen].currentMode.size.height;
CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].currentMode.size.width;
```

The height returned is 1024. This is the long edge of the iPad.
However, if I use the iPad 4 and ask for the height, I get 1536 - which is the shorter edge of the iPad 4. I've tried flipping the iPad around while launching and all that, but nothing seems to yield the result I want (height for the iPad 4 = 2048). Does anyone else have this problem? This appears to be a bug on Apple's side....unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Try using '[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]'

Comment: `applicationFrame` varies depending on whether the app has a status bar and (if I remember correctly) whether the status bar is in double-height mode (tethering, recording audio, etc.). `bounds` is probably the safer bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does sound like a bug, but you might be able to get around it by using `bounds` instead of `currentMode`. The latter property is a measurement of the physical screen and is measured in pixels—and can apparently have arbitrary orientation—whereas the former is the logical screen area, measured in points (what you’re more likely to be laying out your UI in), and should be consistent in size across all existing iPads.

Comment: I agree. Avoid currentMode, you shouldn't really need it. Always work in resolution independent points, and leverage the use of retina graphics via @2x.

Comment: This forces me to use retina graphics via @2x instead of detecting any @ 2x assets. I guess this is appropriate but in my situation, I really wanted to avoid certain files being non-retina duplicates as I have PNGs (with transparency properties) which are fairly large. Was hoping I could just detect the 2048 vs 1024 and scale the image down....darn.

But bounds do work.

Comment: You don’t need to duplicate the files if you’re using UIImage’s `+imageNamed:`—if it can’t find a Retina version of a file, it’ll fall back to scaling up the non-Retina version for you.

Comment: But it will not scale a retina image down to non-retina. I am not okay with losing quality.

Comment: This answer works for me although it is not the ideal solution. I was willing to sacrifice code clarity in favor of less files (in most cases this would be a mistake, I think) but for this specific situation, I felt it could've been valuable. Regardless, I ended up using bounds. Thanks @NoahWitherspoon